# Android Studio Gradle Buiild loading all the time

Tags: android-studio, gradle

everyone:
By command , I can execute all the gradle tasks (such as clean build install). But on the Android studio ,after I click the Button ( Build -> 
Rebuild Project) ,the gradle tasks can work and show the tips that is BUILD SUCCESSFUL . What confuse me is that the gradle build loading all the time?
If I chose another Project ,Android Studio work perfectly . My Android Studio is 2.0 Release ,and JDK is 1.8 version.Platform is Mac .

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like Instant Run functionality side effect.

Comment: I have closed Instant Run . My project has 3 modules . If I shield two and left  only one at the settings.gradle file , I get a error that is Timeout waiting to lock cp_settings class cache for settings file on the Gradle Console . after removed the locked file ,I get this error again .Could you give other tips.Thanks.